# Can't destroy any objects given by ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 classes, `Order` and `Product` where Order has_many Products

`order.products` returns type `Product::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`.

What I am trying to do is destroy every `Product` in `order.products`. The best I can get is that `order.products` will return a empty array. but the records remain in the database. I am so confused as to what is happening and why I can delete these. I have tried the following and none of them actually delete the record in the database.

`order.products.destroy_all`

`order.products.each(&:destroy)`

`order.products.to_a.each(&:destroy)`

Comment: Is there an error message? Or what does happen instead? What do those models look like? What does the log file look like when you try to delete those records? Did you double-check that the records left in the DB are really the ones connected to the order?

Comment: **Hold on a second.** What is it that you're actually trying to do here? If your creating a typical order form or web shop you should have a many to many assocation between orders and products which is stored in a join table. When removing a product from an order you delete the row from the join table (the line item). Not the product as that would cause it to be removed from every order in the system. That would typically look like `order.line_items.destroy_all` or `order.product_ids = []`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to destroy products with joins:

```
Product.joins(:order).destroy_all
```

It will destroy all product which have order.

If you have `null: false` on order_id field in product table you can just do `Product.destroy_all`